# using jquery clone with other function

Tags: jquery, clone

**PS: There were two answer before, and I refresh this page, the answer disappeared, what's going on?**

demo: [demo in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/itemip/2/watch)

html

```
<table>
<tr class='test_tr'>
  <td>
    <select class='test_select'>
      <option value=1>test1</option>
      <option value=2>test2</option>
      <option value=3>test3</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><a href="#" class='test_clone'>clone</a></td>
</tr>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select.test_select').selectmenu();
  $('.test_clone').click(function(){
    var tp = $(this).parents('.test_tr');
    var new_tr = tp.clone(true);
    new_tr.insertAfter(tp);
    tr_func(new_tr);
  })
});
  function tr_func(new_tr){
     $('.test_select',new_tr).selectmenu();
  }
```

After click the clone button and click on the new select, it always affect to the first one. 
Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Please include relevant, formatted code inline (don't just link to jsbin).

Comment: I think it's a bug in `selectmenu` tbh.

Comment: No,it's just a demo, it also in other function, I just refresh the page, and the answer disappear?

Comment: the cloned object has the same id

Comment: Figured out how to circumvent your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has a few interesting aspects:

1. When a row is cloned, all items with an `id` attribute will be cloned as well, causing two elements with the same `#ID`; that's not good. It can be solved by creating a pristine sample row that gets cloned every time you click the button which you then have to "decorate" before it can be used (i.e. apply `.selectmenu()` and click handler).
2. When a `<select>` is cloned, it doesn't retain the selected option. You have to save the `selectedIndex` property and apply it to the cloned version.

Both problems solved looks like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // keep reference to the sample row
    var sample = $('.test_tr.sample');
    // click handler for the clone button
    function cloneRow()
    {
      var parentRow = $(this).parents('.test_tr'),
          selectedOption = parentRow.find('.test_select').prop('selectedIndex');

      setupRow(newRow().insertAfter(parentRow), selectedOption);
    }

    // decorates the new row and sets the correct selected option before applying
    // selectmenu()
    function setupRow(row, selectedOption)
    {
      row
        .find('.test_select')
          .prop('selectedIndex', selectedOption || 0)
          .selectmenu()
          .end()
        .find('.test_clone')
          .click(cloneRow)
          .end()
    }

    // helper function that clones the sample and shows it before handing it over
    // to other code.
    function newRow()
    {
      return sample.clone().show();
    }

    // setup the first row
    setupRow(newRow().appendTo('table'));
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/itemip/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with, less code and no outside functions.

```
$('select.test_select').selectmenu();
$('.test_clone').on('click', function(){
    var $row = $(this).parents('.test_tr');  //get parent tr row
    var $select = $row.find('.test_select'); //get select box
    var selectedIndex = ($select.prop('selectedIndex') || 0); //copy current selectedIndex
    $select = $select.clone(false); //clone select box, withDataAndEvents = false
    $select.prop('selectedIndex', selectedIndex);  //apply selectedIndex
    $select.removeAttr('id'); //remove id as selectmenu will apply the correct id
    var $tbody = $row.parent();
    var $newrow = $row.clone(true); //clone row, withDataAndEvents = true
    $('td:first', $newrow).empty(); //empty the first td
    $('td:first', $newrow).append($select); //append cloned select box
    $tbody.append($newrow); //append row to table
    $('.test_select', $newrow).selectmenu(); //apply jquery.ui.selectmenu
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/syNy3/)

Answer (score 0):

All the cloned select boxes that are generated have the same id. That an example of invalid DOM structure.

May be that's what is causing always the first select menu to open, any of them is clicked.

Comment: .removeAttr('id') after clone?

Comment: Then probably the plugin might misbehave. You need to see plugin code, how the plugin is generating the markup , and how the click events are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Must probably when you do the `clone()` , it clone the menu widget elements as well so make the weird behavior. I tried to update your code to clone from a template element and it worked.

http://jsbin.com/onozeh/1/edit

Comment: It's just clone the first one. I want to clone the value also.

Comment: `jqueryui` would modify the elements `DOM` and when you `clone()` it , you are cloning the  modified one.

Comment: Actually jQuery doesn't clone the selected option.